# NavigationView empty rows in nested hierarchies

Tags: navigation, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and am trying to implement some sort of file browser with hierarchical navigation using NavigationView and NavigationLink. Even though it is technically working, in each "deeper" level empty lines above the new entries appear. It looks like higher level entries keep their respective rows: they are not displayed in deeper levels but leave a blank row, forcing new entries to occupy lower rows.

For example (c.f. attached screenshots): 
Folders "A" and "B" are correctly displayed in row 1&2 (on root level); after selecting folder "A", however, the subfolder "C" and "D" appear in rows 3&4 while rows 1&2 are blank.

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]

**ContentView.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: TreeView(item_id: 0, name: "Root")) {
                Text("Test")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Select"))
        }       
    }
}
```

**TreeView.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TreeView : View {
    var item_id: Int
    var name: String

    var body: some View {
        List(databaseData) { item in
            if item.parent == self.item_id {
                NavigationLink(destination: TreeView(item_id: item.id, name: item.name)) {
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(self.name))
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meanwhile I could figure it out: the problem appears to be that within the list closure an empty row is added whenever the if condition is false. I fixed it by filtering the array provided to list rather than filtering inside the list:

```
    var body: some View {
    List(databaseData.filter{$0.parent == self.item_id}) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: TreeView(item_id: item.id, name: item.name)) {
            Text(item.name)
        }
    }
```

Works in Xcode 11 beta 4.